# Fuzzy statistics bibliography.

Tags: statistics, reference-request

Could someone recommend me fuzzy statistical literature? I have basic knowledge of probability theory and statistics, but this topic is totally new to me. Prefer books I can download, but any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are textbooks on fuzzy statistics, mainly because the term doesn't go in the same direction at all as "frequentist statistics", "Bayesian statistics", or "fiducial statistics". It is not a way to approach statistics but rather a misnomer for `anything and everything that has something to do with statistics and fuzzy sets simultaneously'.

In order to get a general grasp of fuzzy sets I would suggest the Klir-Yuan 1995 textbook (Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications).

The main mathematical model for fuzzy data is a fuzzy random variable. A good theoretical treatment is in the Li-Ogura-Kreinovich book (Limit Theorems and Applications of Set-Valued and Fuzzy Set-Valued Random Variables). A less mathematical, yet still theoretical book is Bandemer and Nather's 1992 Fuzzy Data Analysis (however note the date). More recent and written by engineers is Möller and Beer's Fuzzy Randomness: Uncertainty in Civil Engineering and Computational Mechanics.

The most recent (2006), and probably a good place to start, is Nguyen and Wu's Fundamentals of Statistics with Fuzzy Data. The following survey can be a good complement, as it includes pointers to recent literature and a few bibliometric data:
http://www.seio.es/BEIO/files/BEIOVol30Num1Feb2014-ESTADISTICA.pdf

There is one conference essentially devoted to fuzzy statistics and related topics: the Int. Conf. on Soft Methods in Probability and Statistics. Springer publishes the proceedings, however they will try to charge you hundreds of dollars for a content they don't even have the legal right to sell. Fascinating!

You may find more resources at the following blog: http://spfs.blogspot.com

(Disclaimer: I am both one of the authors of the survey and the person behind the blog.)